# Pass a list of dates to mysql query

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, between

I am trying to do multiple mysql queries to get monthly data from a table, using a for/while loop using a set of dates.

```
For ex, I have a list of dates as :
a = [
    (2022-01-01, 2022-01-31),
    (2022-02-01, 2022-02-28), 
    (2022-03-01, 2022-03-31),
    ...,
    (2022-12-01, 2022-12-31)
]
```

I would like to go through the dates so that I don't have to query 12 times manually. But I get sql compilation error: invalid identifier A:

```
for i in range(12):

    sql_query = select * 
    from table 
    where date between a[i][i] and a[i][i+1];

and pass this query to snowflake db
```

Comment: Are you querying snowflake or mysql? These are not the same thing. Please tag your question accurately, it will help you get the attention of the people who are best able to answer your question.

Comment: Why do you need to run this as 12 different queries? Why not just query the entire range and then process the results in one query? If you need to align records by month, add `trunc(date, 'MONTH')` to your select (or aggregate by month).